# Sharepoint /$value returns Gibberish / strange encoding

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to access a word file from a sharepoint site with the $value which returns the content in unknown format.

GET url is

> [https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/Folder/Document.docx')/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true](https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl=%27/Folder/Document.docx%27)/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true)

Header is

> accept:"application/json; odata=verbose"

Data returned looks like below.

[image]

Also I seem to be having difficulty determining the heirarchy of my sites/groups/lists. Is there a way that i can use to know that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I was really stupid. VSCode opens the files in strange encoding. The actual files are ok and they work with microsoft office.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use following rest api, per my test it works well.

Remember to change the tenant name,site name, library name and doc name for your own (Team1 Doc127,Document.docx in my test):

[https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Team1/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Team1/Doc127/Document.docx')/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true](https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Team1/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/Team1/Doc127/Document.docx%27)/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true)

Comment: Hi, it doesnt make any difference. The returned body is again in strange encoding and i dont konw how to read it.

Comment: Switch to other documents to check if the issue occurs on them.

Comment: Yes it is same for all the documents. Word or Excel etc.

Comment: I can download image files in .jpg format for example.

Comment: From the officail article:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest, there is no error in your code, I suggest you raise a new support ticket to have a dedicated Technical Professional

Comment: Hi, ok i will do that. can you ploease explain how to do that?

Comment: Please refer to: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products?view=o365-worldwide